# Filtering 2 arrays to render a value in React/JSX

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, jsx

I am trying to render a list of items in React. I am looping over a list with all possible values `interests` and comparing it to another list with a subset of those values `event.Interests`. I am comparing the `_id`s saved in the subset list with the `_id`s in the complete list.

`{console.log(e === interest._id)}` returns true 5 times, and interest.Label if logged, will return the name of each of those values.

However, none of them are rendering at all in the UI.

```
event && interests && interests.forEach(interest => (
  event.Interests.filter((e, i) => {
    {console.log(e === interest._id)}
    if (e === interest._id) {
      return <div key={i} className={classNames(classes.categoryContainer, classes.leftPadding)}>
        <div className={classes.categoryWrapLower}>
          <p>{interest.Label}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    }
  })
))
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

Based upon the recommendation posted by `samanime` I changed the forEach and weirdly enough, the filter to a `map` and it worked perfectly.

```
      event && interests && interests.map(interest => (
        event.Interests.map((e, i) => {
          {console.log(e === interest._id)}
          if (e === interest._id) {
            return <div key={i} className={classNames(classes.categoryContainer, classes.leftPadding)}>
              <div className={classes.categoryWrapLower}>
                <p>{interest.Label}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        })
      ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `forEach()` to a `map()`.

The `forEach()` function has no return value, so if you return anything from there, it simply gets thrown away.

The `map()` function will gather up all of the returned values (including `undefined` if you don't return anything) and return them as an array.

In your case, you need to use `map()` and then also add `.filter(Boolean)` after the map to remove all of the `undefined` for scenarios where you don't return anything.

```
event && interests && interests.map(interest => /* your code */).filter(Boolean)
```